# Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty} u(x)$ for $u(x)$ a solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ positive numbers and $u(x)$ function, such that $u''(x)+\alpha u'(x)+\beta u(x)=\gamma$ I need to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} u(x)$ exists and I need to find it.

So I know that $u(x)$ is a solution for the ODE $y''+\alpha y + \beta y = \gamma $ and I know the ODE has a particular solution in the form of $y_p = \frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ so in order to find the general solution I need to find two linearly independent solutions of the homogenous ODE  $y''+\alpha y + \beta y = 0$

The homogenous ODE characteristic equation is $\lambda^2+\alpha\lambda+\beta=0$ which I don't know how to solve but I know that the solution can be:

1. $y_1 = e^{\lambda_1x}$ and $y_1 = e^{\lambda_2x}$ if it has 2 unique real roots
2. $y_1 = e^{\lambda_1x}$ and $y_2 = xe^{\lambda_1x}$ if it has 1 unique real roots
3. $y_1 = e^{ax}\cos{bx}$ and $y_2 = e^{ax}\sin{bx}$ if it has complex roots ($a\pm ib)$

Lets say $y=e^{\lambda x}$ is a solution I get $$\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}+\alpha\lambda e^{\lambda x} + \beta e^{\lambda x} = 0$$ and because $\alpha>0, \beta>0$, $\lambda<0$.

And the same happens for $y=xe^{\lambda x}$, I get $$(\lambda^2+\alpha\lambda+\beta)xe^{\lambda x}+(2\lambda+\alpha)e^{\lambda x}=0$$ which again means $\lambda<0$ so to sum up for now

1. the general solution is $y=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}+\frac{\gamma}{\beta}, \lambda_1<0, \lambda_2<0\Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} y(x)=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$
2. the general solution is $y=C_1e^{\lambda x}+C_2xe^{\lambda x}+\frac{\gamma}{\beta}, \lambda<0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} y(x)=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$

But I don't know how to handle the third case with complex numbers and trigonometric functions, IIRC trigonometric functions don't have a limit in infinity so maybe I need to prove that the third case cannot happen?

Comment: In the third case, the terms $e^{ax} \cos(bx), e^{ax} \sin(bx)$ converge to zero iff $a < 0$, and diverge if $a > 0$. Therefore, if $a < 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x) \to \gamma/\beta$ again.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The complex roots are conjugate, and their sum is $-\alpha$. What can you say of their real part?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. for the third case I have $y=C_1e^{ax}\cos{bx} C_2e^{ax}\sin{bx} + \gamma/\beta$ and from a comment I understand that if $a<0$ the limit is $\gamma/\beta$ but how can I show that?

Comment: The exponential  tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$  and the trigonometric functions are bounded.

Comment: yes but only if $a<0$, if $a \ge 0$ there is no limit, I'm trying to figure out how to prove that $a<0$

Comment: This is in my hint.

Comment: not sure if this is what you intended but I reached $a=-\alpha/2$ and due to $\alpha>0$ means that $a<0$ and the limit exists

Comment: @CforLinux: That's exactly what I meant.